# Generating dictionary in for loop returning last iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, sequence, python-3.6

I'm looping through the following JSON:

```
 "item 1": { 
    "property 1": "value 1",
    "property 2": "value 2",
    "property 3": "value 3"
},
"item 2": {
    "property 1": "value 1",
    "property 2": "value 2",
    "property 3": "value 3"
}
```

I'd like to make a dictionary with the values of the first two keys — `property 1`, `property 2` — for each item (i.e. excluding `property 3`). The code that follows achieves the desired result, but only stores the most recent sequence:

```
for i in JSON:
    value 1 = i["value 1"]
    value 2 = i["value 2"]
    ...
    JSON = json.dumps({'property 1':value 1,'property 2':value 2...})
return json.loads(JSON)

>> "item 2": {
   "property 1": "value 1",
   "property 2": "value 2" ...
   # returns item 2, but I'd like item 1 also
```

How do I store each the output of each `item` without overwriting the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple Iteration.

**Ex:**

```
data = {"item 1": { 
    "property 1": "value 1",
    "property 2": "value 2",
    "property 3": "value 3"
},
"item 2": {
    "property 1": "value 1",
    "property 2": "value 2",
    "property 3": "value 3"
}
}

d = {}
for i in data:
    d[i] = {"property 1": data[i]["property 1"], "property 2": data[i]["property 2"]}
print( d )
```

**Output:**

```
{'item 2': {'property 1': 'value 1', 'property 2': 'value 2'}, 'item 1': {'property 1': 'value 1', 'property 2': 'value 2'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option using the `items` method and a dict comprehension:

```
data = {"item 1": { 
    "property 1": "value 1",
    "property 2": "value 2",
    "property 3": "value 3"
},
"item 2": {
    "property 1": "value 1",
    "property 2": "value 2",
    "property 3": "value 3"
}
}

new_data = {}
for index, value in data.items():
    new_data.update({index: {k:v for k, v in value.items() if k != "property 3"}})
print(new_data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'item 1': {'property 1': 'value 1', 'property 2': 'value 2'},
 'item 2': {'property 1': 'value 1', 'property 2': 'value 2'}}
```